# Maven: including non-java files from more specific directory

Tags: java, maven-3

To include non-java (txt) files from `src/main/java` I defined

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.txt</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

in `pom.xml` and is working well. However defining a more specific directory path like

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java/com/oppballi/kanake</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.txt</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

is not. Is this by design or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look to `target/classes` content.

Since you are defining `src/main/java/com/oppballi/kanake` as a resource root, a txt file such as `src/main/java/com/oppballi/kanake/core/readme.txt` is likely to appear in `target/classes/core/readme.txt`

Comment: Yes you are right, it is under the `target/classes` folder. But the txt files are still not in generated jar file, not in the same package with related class files. Why?

Comment: Hmm. Do you have a custom `maven-jar-plugin` configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to, may be there is no more sub dir to look into

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java/com/oppballi/kanake</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.txt</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```